# amazon ec2 instance unable to resolve host

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, host, resolve

I have a bunch of amazon ec2 instances. Today, for no reason I can determine, three of them became unable to resolve a specific url. When I try `curl <url>`, those three instances say "curl: (6) Could not resolve host", while all the other instances are able to resolve the url and return the correct data. It's only that specific url, as well - all other urls work fine.

What could have caused this? I haven't changed anything on any of the instances, so it's not something I did. How do I find out why it happened?

Comment: just happened to me as well, /etc/hosts looks just fine, and btw curl 127.0.0.1 gives the same error, so it cannot be /etc/hosts or resolv.conf. it happened when i started a process that took quite a bit of memory, and made the instance super slow. once the process was killed, the instance recovered and curl started working again, so it's some aws fluke.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to fix it after enabling that service:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem too.

Comment: `--now` is necessary because it means starting the service immediately after enabling a service. Enabling only is not enough, and need to **start** the service as well.

Answer (score 6):

Check and compare `/etc/resolv.conf` (for Linux instances) between working and non-working hosts. here is info from my Linux instance:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.2
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

In case of Windows instances, check and compare the output of `ipconfig /all` command for DNS entries between working and non-working hosts. here is info from my windows instance:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-************
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : us-west-2.ec2-utilities.amazonaws.com
                                       ec2.internal
                                       us-east-1.ec2-utilities.amazonaws.com
                                       compute-1.internal
                                       us-west-2.compute.internal

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : us-west-2.compute.internal
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Citrix PV Ethernet Adapter #0
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-E6-AB-83-C6-8A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.251(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, March 21, 2014 11:36:17 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, March 25, 2014 5:07:59 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Answer (score 5):

If you’re not using the default VPC, or a VPC created by the VPC wizard, you’ll need to make sure that the `DNS hostname` and `DNS resolution` options are enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same issue. 
This might be the reason of the issue .Disk space full so 
`/etc/resolve.conf` file gets cleared then Its unable to resolved the host

This solution works for me.

Clean the fulled spaces

Update the `resolve.conf` from the working ec2 instance of same vpc

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon Linux, the installation of some binaries requires the static linking of `gclib` which causes a lost of name resolution for certain packages. In my case was `ffmpeg`.

I solved by installing `nscd` :

```bash
yum update -y
yum install nscd -y
service nscd start
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my checklist of things to verify.  Are you 100% sure nobody / nothing changed the following:

- DNS Settings on the instance? (check with dig  to see if name resolution is OK)
- NACL rules on the subnet where your instance is running?
- Security Group rules of the SG attached to your instances?

Seb

Answer (score 0):

[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/59517/89779) will probably solve your issue, as it did mine.  you must fix your hosts file to

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1    my-machine
```

or

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    my-machine
```

where my-machine is the host name that appears at the end of the error message.
(e.g. mine was `domX-A2-33-D9-CB-F4-A8`)

don't forget to reboot your instance from your management console after you have changed the hosts file.  ;)

Comment: How will this solve the issue? 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, which is not externally reachable. I was trying to connect to the server from an external machine, are you saying that amazon is somehow using localhost to produce the dns entries?

Comment: you use BOTH localhost 127.0.0.1 AND 127.0.1.1 machine-name as stated in the "host unreachable" error.  i dont know the technical background behind it, only that it worked for me.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VPC has the below configuration enabled
DNS resolution: Enabled
DNS hostnames: Enabled

As well as correct DHCP options set attached to VPC

Answer (score 0):

It worked after reinstalling resolvconf

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```