# Gitlab Repository not cloning to aws ec2

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ee

I'm trying to clone a repository in my private enterprise git to aws ec2 and it throws error as could not resolve host.

Using Ubuntu Image in `EC2`.

All the ports are open and firewall status is active.

```sh
Cloning into 'node_chatapp'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://*******.com/yjagilanka/node_chatapp.git/': Could not resolve host: ******.corp.com
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to resolve an internal DNS name (`xx.corp.com`). This DNS name probably works inside your company network, but not on the Internet. Do you have a connection between your corporate network and the VPC? For example, a Direct Connect connection or a VPN connection?

Comment: Would https://serverfault.com/a/892201/783 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/54971312/6309 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gitlab corporate is allowed only on private vpn which is not configured in public aws dns.So cloning was failing. Need to create VPC with inter vpn for cloning the same.

Comment: Yash, would you please provide more details on how you resolved this ? I am stuck with a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf.